# Cannot Set Favicon

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, favicon

I'm hosting a free website through [Hostinger](http://hostinger.co.uk), and I can't seem to set the favicon at all no matter what I try. I put it in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico /favicon.ico [L]
```

I my `favicon.ico` in my root folder `/public_html`. And I added it to my page like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

What else can I do? My website is still displaying the default favicon. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try **<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />**

Comment: @bub That didn't work.

Comment: Is it the same result on any browser?

Comment: @bub I don't know. I'm on Chrome. If you're on anything else, the website url is [incro.tk](http://incro.tk).

Comment: I don't want the website. As a develope you HAVE to have the possibility of using most wanted browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set up an infinite redirect. Going from `favicon.ico` to `favicon.ico` to `favicon.ico` to ...

Remove the rewrite rule and change the href attribute to `href="/favicon.ico"`.

Comment: I did all that and nothing changed. :/

Comment: Could you post a link to your site?

Comment: I have two tabs open. incro.tk shows the favicon but www.incro.tk. What's wrong? :/

Comment: I am seeing the favicon on both sites. I recommend doing a rewrite rule for non-`www` to `www` (or the other way) so there is only one website.